# Dynamic naming of download filename from DataTable buttons extension in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h2("Explorer"),

    tabPanel(h3("Inspector"),
             p("Overview of data for a particular sample."),
             selectInput(inputId = "sample",
                         label = h3("Select sample"),
                         selectize = TRUE,
                         choices = names(vcf_tibbles)),
             dataTableOutput("sample_inspector")
            )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sample_inspector <- DT::renderDataTable(

      sample_overview(sample_id = input$sample, vcf_tibbles = vcf_tibbles),
      rownames = FALSE,
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(paging = FALSE,
             dom = 'Bfrtip',
             buttons = list( list(extend = 'csv',   filename =  paste("snp", input$sample, sep = "-")),
                     list(extend = 'excel', filename =  paste("snp", input$sample, sep = "-"))))
      )
}
```

Everything works fine, in that I select a sample and the table correspondingly updates. And if I click CSV or Excel, the corresponding dta downloads. However, **the file name is always wrong**.

It seems that the content of the data table is being updated, but `input$sample` is not being considered with the buttons.

Is there a way to make the filename argument in the buttons also be reactive?

I tried to make the name be the result of a function call, but was unable to get that to work either.

Thanks!

Comment: you have written ```sammple_overview``` (with two m) at the beginning of the ```server``` part, is it voluntary or is it a mistake?

Comment: thanks @bretauv - that was indeed a typo in this illustrative subset of code. (it had nothing to do with the problem). fixed

Comment: two questions: can you provide a sample of ```vcf_tibbles```? and what is the sample_overview function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sample_inspector <- DT::renderDataTable(
    iris,
    rownames = FALSE,
    extensions = 'Buttons',
    options = exprToFunction(
      list(paging = FALSE,
           dom = 'Bfrtip',
           buttons = list( 
             list(extend = 'csv',   filename =  paste("snp", input$sample, sep = "-")),
             list(extend = 'excel', filename =  paste("snp", input$sample, sep = "-"))))
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: How can you tell what options are available? I read https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.extend, but there is no mention of `filename`.